# Paid via PayPal with bank account, but was a couple dollars short

Tags: united-states, bank-account, paypal

Paying for an item from a store in another currency. Last time I did this, to the same store, PayPal showed me the current USD charge instead of just the foreign currency before I actually hit submit, but this time just submit anyway, so when all was said and done, PayPal would charge more than was in my bank account.

I quickly ran up to the bank within an hour and deposited the difference, since it takes a few days for charges to show up on my bank account from PayPal, but will the charge go through or will it be declined because of the original amount in the bank account?

PayPal account shows everything as completed in the order, but I'm unsure...

Comment: It depends on how quickly Paypal and your bank process these transactions. It's hard to provide a certain answer.

Comment: Does PayPal have a credit card attached to it in addition to the bank?  For me I have a credit card as backup: if the bank draft fails, it will secondarily charge to the credit card.

Comment: Also, have you looked at your Paypal account?  It should tell you if something fails to go through.

Comment: @Joe, I do have my immediate back-up source as my credit card, which doesn't have any charge on it (yet). And on my PayPal account, it has all statuses in the transaction as "Completed." (Payment to seller, Add Funds from Bank Account, and the Currency Conversion) When I pay through Paypal with my bank account, however, it always takes at least 1 day for the transaction to show up in my bank account (ie. PayPal date 1/27, bank account date 1/28).

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE for anyone else in this situation: the payment went through! As I said in the original post, my PayPal purchases don't show up on my bank account until at least a day later, and I just checked and the total PayPal amount had been deducted.

(My account does not have overdraft coverage, so it says transactions with insufficient funds will be denied, but I won't get overdraft fees.)

I made the PayPal purchase at 6:08am and had the difference deposited into my bank account less than an hour later, at 7:02am on the 28th, and the full payment showed up today, the 29th, in my bank account.

Thank you to everyone for their input on this! I guess the only way to really know is to wait it out! If anyone else is short a few dollars when paying via their bank account's instant transfer on PayPal, just try to be quick and deposit the difference as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how your and your bank have agreed to handle overdrafts for that account:

- Some people have it setup so that you would have a negative balance funds from another account type will bring the balance back to zero.
- You can also setup an automatic loan to cover these situations.

Of course there can be monthly limits on the number of occurrences, and the amount of overdraft.

In other cases the transaction is denied becasue you have not authorized overdraft protection.

There can also be fees for overdraft protection.

Comment: My account does not have overdraft coverage, so it says transactions with insufficient funds will be denied, but I won't get overdraft fees. If this is the case, will it just go through once and fail, then be tried again in a few days via PayPal?